# ESRI Local Government Park Locator App Template Deployment Issues

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-local-government

I am currently trying to implement esri's newest release of the [Park Locator | ArcGIS for Local Government](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/park-locator/) and I have been having a few issues that I can't seem to resolve.

First,  If I just change the web map id to the map published on our server in the config.js file on our server and I don't change any of the basemap settings I can get the app to partially work but if I look and the js console on chrome the app gets the following error say a token is required:

[image]

Also, when I go to change basemaps the app locks up.

When I search by Activity it throws a subsequent error which looks like it is related to the first:

[image]

Second,  if I change my basemap settings to the basemap group and owner in our orgnatation I get a javascript alert saying that I need to set the Geometry Service.  The issue sounds like something similar to [this](https://github.com/Esri/map-and-app-gallery-template/issues/106) issue.

Here are the links to the two apps I have running to see the issues in real time:

https://gis.linncounty.org/webapps/gis/parklocator/

https://gis.linncounty.org/webapps/gis/parklocator_basemaps/ - This one gets the alert popup saying to provide a geometry service.

I followed esri's tutorial on setting the app up.  I am not sure what settings I have wrong or how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Your basemap issue is giving this error.

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://gis.linncounty.org/webapps/gis/parklocator/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can you try and switch to https from the ESRI service? It works when just pasting the below in the browser, so try it in the app
'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json'